# How do vertices at infinity work?

Tags: opengl, graphics

At this [tutorial on shadow volumes](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems/gpugems_ch09.html), there are necessary vertices at infinity. I understand the concept of points at infinity, I just don't understand how they work with openGL.

What happens in the perspective divide if the w of a vertex is 0? Are all points at infinity mapped to some point on the edge of the -1 to 1 range in NDC space? How is that achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how the hardware internally works, but it depends on your projection matrix.
I'll try a hopefully intuitive explanation:
According to the perspective projection matrix in http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html
if your far plane is at a finite distance any vertex with w=0 will be clipped away since a multiplication of (x,y,z,0) by the projection matrix will result in a value outside [-1,1].
The shadow volume will be missing the back cap and deliver wrong results (finite shadow volumes could fix this).
If your far plane is at infinity the projection matrix will look like this:

```
*  0  0  0
0  *  0  0
0  0 -1  *
0  0 -1  0
```

A multiplication with (x,y,z,0) leads to (*,*,z,z)=(*,*,1) after the perspective divide.
The z component (of the back cap of the shadow volume) now lies within [-1,1] and will be captured by the depth buffer.

More on infinite projection matrices: http://www.terathon.com/gdc07_lengyel.pdf